# 250 LED control

Tags: led, multiplexer, shift-register, plc

I am in the process of designing an automated rock climbing wall that will have 250 monocolor LEDs lit in a predetermined pattern that will be changing every 10 seconds. My controller (actually a PLC) is a Cutouch CT1721C so I have 82 IO ports of which I want to use as few as possible because the controller will be stationary and the lights will be rotating around it. I haven't even attempted to figure out a rotating coupler yet.

I have found instructions to make a multiplexer that could more than handle this, but it is on the pricier side.  I have also been looking at shift registers, mainly 74HC595 as they are cheap, but I would need 32 of them. I have seen other chips that seem like they would be usable, but some of them are just plain hard to find.

There is something here I haven't thought of, or am unaware of, that could make this a lot easier. I am open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: Do you need to have the LEDs appear to be independently controlled? How much current and forward voltage do they each require?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes.  As far as your second question, the Cutouch has 24V outputs, but my motors are 210VAC so I have options.  The circuits themselves have not been designed yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: An LED driver with a high channel count, such as the Austria Microsystems [AMS1130](http://www.ams.com/eng/Products/Lighting-Management/LED-Driver-ICs/AS1130), an LED driver for 132 individual LEDs, with inbuilt constant current regulation and I2C interface. The linked page itself has a block diagram for driving 264 LEDs using two of the LED controllers on a single I2C bus. You would thus need just 4 lines to interface with the rotating unit.

[image: AMS1130 block diagram]

**Option 2**: Expanding on the answer provided by supercat. Use WS2812B RGB LEDs which have a digitally addressable controller ([WS2811](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf)) integrated into each. Large numbers of these LEDs can be hooked up in series, and individually addressed using just one data line, plus 12 Volt supply and ground connections.

WS2812 LEDs are sold in individual [PLCC packages](http://www.ebay.com/itm/250-pc-WS2812-Superbright-5050-RGB-LEDs-w-Built-In-WS2811-IC-Addressable-Color-/160948000594?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item25793f9752), and also [prewired](http://www.ebay.com/itm/250-Pre-soldered-WS2812B-LED-Heatsink-5V-5050-RGB-WS2811-IC-Built-in-12cm-Wire-/281217067844?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4179d7eb44) with 3 lines each in and out. These links are for lots of 250 LEDs each from eBay.

[image: WS2812] [image: WS2812 prewired]

While the question mentions single-color LEDs, unfortunately I haven't been able to find any individually addressable, serially cascaded single-color LEDs. Also, given the mass-manufacture price of the RGB LEDs mentioned, it might actually be cheaper to use these RGB LEDs. Just send data representing any one color, or even equal values of R, G and B to result in white.

Comment: These may be exactly what I am looking for, I am currently buying a lot of 10 for some testing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to put the 250 LEDs on the wall however you wish, but electrically they are wired into a 16x16 grid and you scan horizontally and vertically through the grid. It doesn't have to look like a grid on the wall, but that is just the way you can scan it to turn them on or off.

This method does not (necessarily) require any shift registers or multiplexers, but you will need a microcontroller that can scan and drive the ROW and COLUMN of the matrix.  There are many ways to setup ROW/COLUMN scanning like this, depending on your needs.

The microcontroller could be an Arduino, these are easy to program for what you want to do.

You would have a matrix in memory of which LED should be on and which should be OFF. Then scan the output ports ROW X COLUMN and turning on each LED that should be on.  Do this for 10 seconds, then change the matrix data in memory to change the look of the LEDs on the wall.

Depending on the types of LEDs you are using, you may require row and column drivers, such as the MAX7219. Much of what you choose depends on the forward voltage and current requirements of the LEDs.

Finally, since I mentioned the Arduino earlier, there are plenty of example hardware and software for ROW/COLUMN scanning like this on the Arduino website (and many more can be found on the net)

Comment: I am trying to stay away from using an Arduino for this project because they are used so often with our major and projects.  This is inherently making things much more difficult, but I think more rewarding in the long run. Hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Some companies make strings of serially-connected single-color or multi-color LED modules which allow an arbitrary number of lights to be controlled using one or two I/O pins.  I've bought some nice color ones from a company in China that cost about US$0.40 per LED (US$20 per string of 50).  Five strings of fifty would cost about $100 plus shipping.  Single-color modules might be cheaper, but I haven't priced them.

Comment: Pointer to single-color individually addressable discrete (not strip) LEDs would be useful, I need some, but haven't found any.

Comment: know this is a bit late and you've probably discovered them by now, but there's heaps of ws2812 based individually addressable 5050 rgb led strips now  on ebay for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few projects with a lot of LEDs. The big challenge is dealing with the wiring; for 250 LEDs you are talking 250 separate wires running back to your controller system. That's going to be quite complex to deal with, and the wire is going to be pricey.

Going with a distributed system using WS2812-based RGB LEDs will be far easier; you supply power to them and the various data lines chain together. They can be found for something like $0.25/each.

They are finicky to drive, and I'm not sure a PLC is going to be able to generate the waveform required. There are some good libraries for the arduino.